# Word for where speakers and honoree sit at a comedic roast?

Tags: single-word-requests

I've heard this word a few times when watching roasts, and was never able to look up what I thought I was hearing.

I don't know the IPA so I will link to a clip of someone saying it: [@3m11s](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vK8ID0Eki68#t=189) (word start with "d").

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe a '[dais](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Dais)' ?

> raised platform, as in a lecture hall, for speakers or honored guests.

Comment: "Joe Namath is the Man of the Hour. Appearing with Dean on the dais are guests Don Meredith, Weeb Eubank, Paul "Bear" Bryant, Dick Butkus, Jim Plunkett, David Janssen, Angie Dickinson, Archbishop Fulton J. Sheen, Foster Brooks, Charlie Callas, Joey Bishop, Rich Little and Slappy White."

Comment: Wow, that was fast! You have great ears or query skills.

Comment: No Red Buttons? What kind of roast is that, where *everybody* got a dinner?

Answer (score -2):

*Dais* is what he used but in America "hot seat," is what it is called when one is not trying to show off.